# Counting comments by sheet wih apps script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, comments, drive

I need to count comments in a Google sheet by author.

I used  a Google Apps Script library and Drive API, i reached this code:

```
function countCommentsInSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ssId).getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).getComments();
  const contar = res.length;
  Logger.log(res);
  Logger.log(contar);    
  }
```

and i get this result:

```
2:12:40 PM  Notice  Execution started
2:12:46 PM  Info    [{comment=[{comment=second comment
, user=Manuel Ocampo}], range={row=2.0, a1Notation=B2, col=2.0}}, {comment=[{user=Manuel Ocampo, comment=first comment
}], range={row=1.0, col=1.0, a1Notation=A1}}]
2:12:46 PM  Info    2.0
2:12:42 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Now i need to filter the result by the author of the comment, can you help me to complete the code and filter results by author?

Answer (score 1):

### Recommendation:

You can use a `for()` loop to access the elements of the `object` and identify the users who had commented on the sheet. You can then use another `for()` loop to count the number of comments per user.

Let me know if this code works for you:

```
function countCommentsInSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ssId = ss.getId();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(ssId).getSheetByName(sheet.getSheetName()).getComments();
  var users = [];

  for (var x in res) {
    //This loop iterates through all of the comments captured and stores the users in an array.
    if (users.indexOf(res[x].comment[0].user) == -1) users.push(res[x].comment[0].user);
  }

  for (var y in users) {
    //This loop then counts and logs the number of comments per user.
    var commentCount = 0;
    for (var z in res) {
      if (res[z].comment[0].user == users[y]) commentCount++
    }
    Logger.log(`${users[y]}: ${commentCount}`)
  }
}
```

Note that the code above does not count the replies to the comments. If you'd like to count the replies as well, you can replace both of the `for()` loops above with the following:

```
  for (var x in res) {
    //This loop iterates through all of the comments and replies captured and stores the users in an array.
    for (var a in res[x].comment) {
      if (users.indexOf(res[x].comment[a].user) == -1) users.push(res[x].comment[a].user);
    }
  }

  for (var y in users) {
    //This loop then counts and logs the number of comments and replies per user.
    var commentCount = 0;
    for (var z in res) {
      for (var b in res[z].comment) {
        if (res[z].comment[b].user == users[y]) commentCount++;
      }
    }
    Logger.log(`${users[y]}: ${commentCount}`)
  }
```

### Reference:

- [for() loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you have any questions or clarifications to the answer posted above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I´m getting an error in the output: ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
countCommentsInSheet @ getComments.gs:11```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not encountering any errors running the script. By any chance, have you made any modifications before running it? And do you still have the `DocsServiceApp` added to your project's library?

Comment: I tried in a blank sheet and it worked, thanks you so much